# (CSS) My fixed footer overlaps my content

Tags: html, css, sticky-footer

So I am having an issue using a fixed footer. Essentially what is happening is  the footer will get stuck at the bottom of the browser window but not the bottom page, and covers some of the content.

```html
<body>
    <nav class="fixed-nav-bar">
      <div id="menu">
       <a class="sitename" href="index.html"><h1>Sitename</h1></a>
       <a class="show" href="#hidemenu"><img class="menubur" src="img/menu.svg" alt="menu"></a>
        <ul class="menu-items">
         <li><a href="shop.html">shop</a></li>
         <li><a href="portfolio.html">portfolio</a></li>
         <li><a href="contact.html">contact</a></li>
         <li><a href="log.html">log</a></li>
         <li><a href="about.html">about</a></li>
        </ul>
       </div>
      </nav>
      <section class="content">
        <section class="about">
       <section class="floated">
        <img src="img/monkey.jpg" alt="monkey">
       </section>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
       <div class="faqs">
       <button class="accordion">Question 1</button>
       <div class="panel">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
       </div>
       <button class="accordion">Question 2</button>
       <div class="panel">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
       </div>
       <button class="accordion">Questions 3</button>
       <div class="panel">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
       </div>
       </div>
      </section>
      </section>
      <footer class="footer">
       <p class="footer-links">
        <a href="http://www.instagram.com/">Instagram</a>
        <a href="http://www.facebook.com/">Facebook</a>
        <a href="http://www.twitter.com/">Twitter</a>
        <a href="https://www.tumblr.com/blog/">Tumblr</a>
        <a href="http://www.snapchat.com">Snapchat</a>
       </p>
       <p class="footer-company-name">Name &copy; 2017</p>
      </footer>
        </body>
```

And the CSS:

```
body {
   margin-bottom: 100px;
   clear: both;
}

.fixed-nav-bar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 9999;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000033;
}

.content {
    margin-top: 100px;
}

.fixed-nav-bar li, .fixed-nav-bar a {
  background: #fff;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
}
.menu {
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  background: #fff;
}
.menu-items {
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    padding: 0px;
  background: #fff;
}
.sitename {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
  background: #fff;
}
.menu-items li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.menu-items a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.show, .hide {
    display: none;
    padding-left: 15px;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center left;
    color: #dde1e2;
}
.footer{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font: normal 18px sans-serif;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-top: 80px;
}



.footer .footer-company-name{
    margin: 0;
}

.footer .footer-links{
    padding: 35px 0 23px;
    margin: 0;
}

.footer .footer-links a{
    display:inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
}
```

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7taxrv1x/4/

I have tried a few solutions on the subject, some of which are in the footer. What I do not want is like the solution here: [My Footer Floats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20085137/my-footer-floats/20114486#20114486)

Comment: Why is the `position:fixed` in the `nav` element instead of in the `footer` itself?

Comment: I'm trying to get the footer to the bottom of the page, I guess sticky might not be the right word, the header was sticky, I probably should have omitted that whole section.

Comment: Try removing it from the `nav`, then place it in the `footer` instead

Comment: likely a result of your wrapper div's height or position property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this by removing the bottom margin from your page

```
body {
    //remove margin-bottom: 100px;
    clear: both;
}
```

And and changing your footer styles to:

```
.footer{
    //remove position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font: normal 18px sans-serif;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-top: 80px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In CSS file comment or remove the `margin-bottom: 100px;` from body selector and `position: absolute;` from .footer selector.